# How can I convert data to integer from string when I have data using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am getting data as string and would like to add in Array. But Data I am getting is as String and looking to store as Integer.

Code :

```
             public static List<Integer> PriceData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             public static String FinalPrice;


                       Pattern Pricepattern = Pattern.compile("Price\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)");
                       Matcher Pricematcher = Pricepattern.matcher(Content);
                       if(Pricematcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
                           FinalPrice = Pricematcher.group(1);
                       }

                      try
                      {

                      PriceData.add(Integer.parseInt(FinalPrice));

                      }
                      catch(NumberFormatException N)

                      {

                          System.out.println("Invalid Price Data");


                      }
```

**Output :**

**FinalPrice** : "$10.35"

**PriceData** : It always goes to exception. Here I want to store **10.35**.

If I declare **Finalprice** as Integer then also have same problem.

Comment: Use `Price\\s*:\\s*\\S*?(\\d[^\\s"]*)` if the number format is unknown and try `Float.parseFloat(FinalPrice);`

Comment: @stribizhev - Thanks a lot. It works:). You can post it as answer.

Comment: I think all the answers below work too, choose any :) If you think my answer is the best, I will post with explanations.

Comment: @stribizhev - Thanks. One more thing is , I need to get only those price which is less then so , When I am checking condition `PriceData.get(i)<100` , So in debug I can see `16.95<100` , Condition should fall to True but it's getting false. Am I doing any mistake here?

Comment: I think you should make sure you are using float values, [like this](https://ideone.com/w3cTS1).

Comment: @stribizhev - thanks.`100.0f` works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your regex to catch price only and also you should parse to float or double. Integer has no floating point so it throws exception. Also - NumberFormatException is runtime exception so you don't need try/catch here. Here's example:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        String finalPrice = null;
        String price = "Price : \"$10.35\"";
        String regex = "Price\\s:\\s\"\\$(\\d+.\\d+)\"";
        Pattern Pricepattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher Pricematcher = Pricepattern.matcher(price);
        if(Pricematcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
            finalPrice = Pricematcher.group(1);
        }
        float parsedPrice = Float.parseFloat(finalPrice);
        System.out.println(parsedPrice);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `FinalPrice.substring(1)` to get another string without the `$` or you can include the `$` character in your pattern (outside the capture group).

In either case you're left with `"10.35"` so you actually need to be using [`Float.parseFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat-java.lang.String-)